# Is the AndroidKeystore app specific or device specific?

Tags: java, android

I just want to ask that the AndroidKeystore API used for storing keypair is device specific or app specific. I want to ask if two app using the AndroidKeyStore to store their keypair, then the information for both app will go into same keystore or they will have different keystore containers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The keystore is app specific. You are allowed to choose the same keystore if you publish two apps, or choose a different keystore. Each has different pros and cons. Some of this is explained in the [signing considerations section here].(https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#considerations)

If you choose the same keystore for your app it makes various things possible, like code or data sharing through permissions. This is only possible for apps signed with the same key.

On the other hand, suppose in the future you want to sell your app to another company. This can happen to small app developers, where another large game or app development company wants to acquire their app (and they can make a lot of money). If you have signed all your apps with the same key it is very difficult, as the large company needs to be able to sign the app they acquired, so you have to give them your signing key. But this makes it possible for them to produce versions of all your apps, which is not good security practice.

If it was me I would:

- choose a different signing key for each app
- have my app signing done by [Google Play signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423), then there are no worries if you lose or compromise your key (or keystore password), or if an annoyed employee takes advantage of your trust to abuse your key.

Answer (score 0):

**Keystore API for storage is App specific.**

Read this...

Use the KeyChain API when you want system-wide credentials. When an app requests the use of any credential through the KeyChain API, users get to choose, through a system-provided UI, which of the installed credentials an app can access. This allows several apps to use the same set of credentials with user consent.

Use the Android Keystore provider to let an individual app store its own credentials that only the app itself can access. This provides a way for apps to manage credentials that are usable only by itself while providing the same security benefits that the KeyChain API provides for system-wide credentials. This method requires no user interaction to select the credentials.

You can read this on the official site https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#WhichShouldIUse

Answer (score -1):

It is Application Specific not a device specific.

In terms of what you do with it for Android and probably what you're looking for since you mention signing apk's, it is your certificate. You are branding your application with your credentials. You can brand multiple applications with the same key, in fact, it is recommended that you use one certificate to brand multiple applications that you write. It easier to keep track of what applications belong to you.

Answer (score -1):

It is app specific. But you can use same keystore for multiple apps.

Important!!!!!! Keep more copies of key file. If your app is pulished on play store and you missed the keyfile, you never able to provide updates for your app.

You need to build apk with same keystore if your app is already live on playstore otherwise google will not accept your build. You need start again from fresh upload with different package name. App with same package name is also not accepted. You will loose all your app’s rating and download figures as well.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but already know about the application signing and other processes with keystore. My question is different, I want to store crytographic keys into keystore for two applications. 
If you have any official document about 'Key store is app specific.". Please share a official link for same.